# Retrieve the previous indexed record in a list, if exists

Tags: c#

I am using .NET 3.5 . My requirement is to traverse through a list of objects ordered descending by date, find a match for a particular record, capture that object and then, IF a record exists on a date prior to that, which means the captured object's index minus one (if exists), capture this object too, which means my output list can have either one record or two records depending on whether there was a previous dated record or not. Is there a clean way of achieving this ?

I tried capturing index of matched record and going for previous index by adding -1 to index >> Risk of index out of bounds exception if the previous element does not exist.

How can I avoid the index out of bound exception, yet check for the existence of previous element , if exists ? I am sure there is a much cleaner way of doing it rather than the way I am trying. So I am reaching out to you to advice if there is a nicer way of doing this....

Any advise is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I am trying ElementAtOrDefault() now......Hope it fits my purpose....

Comment: Please post your code so we can be able to help you!

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas. I got the fix using all the ideas provided by you all. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below. Object is just a datetimeoffset, but should illustrate LINQ query. You are looking for .Top(2) (this could be more complicated if you need this grouped by something):

LinqPad sample below, but should be easily pasted into console app.

```
void Main()
{
    var threeItems = new List<DateTimeOffset>(new[] { DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-2) });
    var twoItems = new List<DateTimeOffset>(new[] { DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1) });
    var oneItem = new List<DateTimeOffset>(new[] { DateTimeOffset.Now });

    ShowItems(GetItems(threeItems));
    ShowItems(GetItems(twoItems));
    ShowItems(GetItems(oneItem));
}

IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> GetItems(List<DateTimeOffset> items)
{
    return items
        .OrderByDescending(i => i)
        .Select(i => i)
        .Take(2);
}

void ShowItems(IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List of Items:");

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for will require using the List.IndexOf to find the index of the matching item, then retreive the previous item if there is a datetime before the date you have searched for. My example here uses an object called listObject which contains a datetime as well as other properties;

```
        DateTime searchDate = DateTime.Parse("26/01/2019");

        var orderedList = listObjects.OrderBy(x => x.DateProperty).ToList();
        listObject matchingItem = orderedList.First(x => x.DateProperty.Date == searchDate.Date);   //gets the first matching date
        listObject previousMatching = orderedList.Any(x => x.DateProperty.Date < searchDate.Date) ? orderedList[orderedList.IndexOf(matchingItem) - 1] : null;  //returns previous if existing, else returns null
```